# Java Method Confusion with Chars

Tags: java, for-loop, methods, indexing, char

I'm attempting to write a method that takes in a string and an array and print out the following...

```
--- Name is "Abe"---
Adorable
Beautiful
Elegant

--- Name is "bob"---
Beautiful
Outstanding
Beautiful
```

My code...

```
public static void printReport(String name, String[] sortedArray)
{
    System.out.println(name);
    char c = '\0';
    for (int i = 0; i <name.length()-1;i++)
    {
        c = name.charAt(i);
        int index = c-'A';
        System.out.println(sortedArray[index]);
    }
}
}
```

Where name is the... well name, and sortedArray is an array of 26 adjectives in alphabetical order. I'm attempting to use the numerical values of chars to print out the correct adjective. I'm getting an error on

```
System.out.println(sortedArray[index]);
```

and can't seem to figure out why. Any and all help is much appreciated.

Comment: Something you may want to try instead is using a map object where characters map to string, that way you don't need to worry about sorting and creating an index based off of character.  Also, what error are you seeing?

Comment: what is the error? ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assuming your input will be in ALL CAPS, but it isn't, so when you reach the `'b'` in `"Abe"`, you run into trouble. `'b' - 'A'` is in effect `98 - 65` (`33`), as `(int)'b'` is 98 and `(int)'A'` is 65. `33` is out of range for the `0`..`25` (inclusive) array.

Make the character upper case before doing the subtraction. It's probably a good idea as well to check your input, e.g., don't assume the user isn't going to type something like `'$'` (which would give you the index `-29`). :-)